# 404 for simple redirect to /filename.html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I want to redirect to a certain html file in root when the user enters the domain.com. Simple as that. Get an 404.

```
RewriteRule .* /intro.html [NC,L]
```

Any ideas?

I have tried this in  already:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: You can't have a 404 which also redirects to another page. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like you might be looking for an HTML 301 error instead of a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ /intro.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer. I copied exactly this into my .htaccess at domain.com/test and it won't redirect. I get 404. I checked phpinfo() now and I don't see the mod_rewrite module/option. Are there any other possibilities you know of?

Comment: Sorry getting very late here so just a quick response. Please check your Apache config and make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled.